# Find the size in an ID using regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently having a small problem with the following regex in PHP:

```
preg_match_all('/(.*)(XS|S|M|XL|XXL|L)(.*)/i', '00236XL00', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

It returns `L` for the size when I want `XL` in this case.

It works fine if I supply an ID with just `L` (e.g. 002465L00) in it.

Can you tell me what I did wrong?

I tried moving the `L` to the end of the group but it did not help.

Comment: The problem is that I also have IDs that look like this: DD-2465XL07 and XX-2465XL07.

Comment: is there a way to make only the middle group greedy?

Comment: The following regex did it for me: /([A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9]+|[0-9]+)(XS|S|M|XL|XXL|L)(\w*)/i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first group, `(.*)`, is greedy, and will match as much as it can. Since the second group will still match if the first one "takes" `00236X`, that is what will happen. The simplest fix, if the data presented above is typical, is to change the `.` to `[0-9]`. Will this still match your data? If not, please give more examples.

To avoid the greedyness, you can make the other groups lazy instead, by using the `?` operator. So, something like `/(.*?)(XS|S|M|XL|XXL|L)(.*)/i` should work.

Comment: I was about to give the same answer. I'd use a regex similar to this `\d*(X?S|M|X{0,2}L)\d*`

Comment: @KurzedMetal: I believe csupnig wants to capture the other groups too, but in essence, yes.

Answer (score -1):

Seems that your ID's are only digits surrounding the size code.
So what about to look for `non-digit` characters?

```
preg_match_all('/([^0-9]+)/i', '00236XL00', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

EDIT after author's comment:

```
preg_match_all('/[A-Z][A-Z]\-\d+([A-Z]+)\d+/i', 'XX-00236XL00', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but as I noted in the comment to my answer, I'd guess that the OP wants to capture the all groups his original regex does, although slightly differently.

Comment: @carlpett (I talked to the anonymous user. I hate downvotes without give reasons)... About this answer: You can manage all matching results like this: `foreach ($arr as $vector) { // manage $vector }`. But you must use `PREG_SET_ORDER`: `preg_match_all($reg_exp, $data, $arr, PREG_SET_ORDER)`. It's a very clean way to code.